# Google Analytics Reporting API - Get Activity data via Client ID

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-php-sdk

I am trying to get user activity data via his client id using Google Analytics api. Take a look at the below image:

[image]

Now highlighted text is users client id, it could be user id too, and when I trying to get it via Google's playground, I get the correct response and activity data which is required, like:

[image]

and this is the response:
[image]

which is required and OK.

but I want this data via API, and have searched the web to get it, but nothing helped me.

Here is sample code [Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) showing i.e.

```
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

I do found a class for adding user to request i.e.

```
$user = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_User();
$user->setType("CLIENT_ID");
$user->setUserId("660467279.1539972080");
```

but this class `Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest` which accepts conditions/filters for query does not have such method to accept `user` object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this function: `$analytics->userActivity->search()`.

```
$search = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SearchUserActivityRequest();

$search->setViewId($VIEW_ID); // Google Analytics View ID

$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
$dateRange->setEndDate("today");
$search->setDateRange($dateRange);    

$user = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_User();
$user->setType("USER_ID"); // or CLIENT_ID if you are not using custom USER ID views
$user->setUserId($user_id); // The actual user's ID as stored in your DB passed to GA

$search->setPageSize(10); // Number of results you want to pull
$search->setUser($user);

return $analytics->userActivity->search($search); // Perform the search query.
```

Alternatively you can also pass the params to `search()` like:

```
$params = [
   'metrics' => //Your comma separated desired metrics
   'dimmensions' => //Your comma separated custom dimmentions
]

return $analytics->userActivity->search($search, $params);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).